# how to add a time function to an variable in swift

Tags: swift

I'm trying to figure out how I can write an function that for every 15 seconds adds "1" integer into a variable. So everytime 15 seconds passes: myVar: int += 1

I have tried to setup an timer:

```
myTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(playFunc), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, just pass `15.0` instead of `1.0` to your timer call like this:

```
myTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(15.0, target: self, selector: #selector(playFunc), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

Given that you have a variable `myVar` somewhere in your class

```
var myVar = 0  // or initialize it to whatever you like
```

you'll just need to implement `playFunc` which will be called every 15 seconds by the timer:

```
func playFunc() {
    self.myVar += 1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply change this:

```
myTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(playFunc), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

to this: (Changing `1.0` to `15.0`)

```
myTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(15.0, target: self, selector: #selector(playFunc), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

Or you could do this:

```
var timesPlayed = 0

func playFunc() {
    timesPlayed += 1

    if timesPlayed % 15 == 0 {
        myVar += 1
    }
}
```

What this does is every time the function is run it will try see if it is dividable by 15 and if so then it means the function has run 15 times which will then add 1 to your variable.